# get error Invalid request (Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError) when fastlane match

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, fastlane

I use fastlane `match` for build my ios app and store cert and provisioning profile in google cloud bucket

Today after I ran `fastlane match`, I got error `Invalid request (Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError)` I don't know why. I thought my json key is expired then I generate new google cloud key again but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure it out? I'm facing the exact same issue.